# Gulp says live reload is reloading but browser doesn't?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Here's the log in the terminal:

```
[10:12:09] Using gulpfile ~/somelocalpath/gulpfile.js
[10:12:09] Starting 'watch'...
[10:12:09] Starting server...
[10:12:09] Finished 'watch' after 21 ms
[10:12:09] Server started http://localhost:8888
[10:12:09] LiveReload started on port 35729
[10:12:09] Running server
[10:12:47] Starting 'reload'...
[10:12:47] Finished 'reload' after 13 ms
[10:13:43] Starting 'reload'...
[10:13:43] Finished 'reload' after 1.75 ms
```

Here's the gulp.js file:

```
"use strict";

const gulp = require("gulp");
const connect = require("gulp-connect");

gulp.task("watch", function() {
    connect.server({
        root: "somelocalfolder",
        livereload: true,
        port: 8888
    });
    gulp.watch("./somelocalfolder/**/*", ["reload"]);
});
gulp.task("reload", function() {
    return gulp.src("./somelocalfolder/**/*").pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

But the browser doesn't automatically reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the [extension](http://livereload.com/extensions/) installed in your browser?